# HttpClient GET запрос с форматом JSON

Tags: c#, json, http, httpclient

Использую класс `HttpClient` и при `GET` на `API` вместо `JSON` формата получаю строку такого типа. Хотя если зайти через браузер там нормально  возвращает.

```
{\"error\":false,\"message\":\"\\u0417\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0441 \\u0432\\u044b\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u043d\\u0435\\u043d \\u0443\\u0441\\u043f\\u0435\\u0448\\u043d\\u043e\",\"response\":[{\"id_room\":5,\"id_doctor\":2,\"full_name\":\"\\u0413\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u043d \\u041f\\u0435\\u0442\\u0440 \\u041c\\u0438\\u0445\\u0430\\u0439\\u043b\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\"},{\"id_room\":6,\"id_doctor\":3,\"full_name\":\"\\u0417\\u0430\\u0445\\u0430\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0410\\u043b\\u0435\\u043a\\u0441\\u0435\\u0439 \\u0421\\u0435\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435\\u0435\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\"},{\"id_room\":4,\"id_doctor\":4,\"full_name\":\"\\u0421\\u0443\\u0432\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0414\\u043c\\u0438\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u0439 \\u0421\\u0435\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435\\u0435\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\"}]}"
```

---

```
public async void Getasdas()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    UserList user = new UserList();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.110/mh_api/v1/rooms/1");
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перекодируй в JSON. Это обычная практика. Необходимо выполнить JSON encode (к сожалению в C# не знаю, как это реализовать, ибо не писал на нем, но данная проблема появляется не только на C#).

ИСПРАВЛЕНО:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

Comment: Спасибо, решило вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Использую **HttpWebRequest** .

```csharp
        private string getContent(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 ....";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            response.Close();
            return output.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно с использованием `HttpClient`. Там потом удобнее `POST` запросы посылать.